# Ubuntu unity - remove/hide unknown tray icon

Tags: ubuntu

I have freshly installed a Ubuntu Unity 23.10 today,and noticed the following icon on the top bar.

[image]

How can i remove this Pencil icon?
I dont know from what application it is.

[image]